# I'm running a maven command for Jhipster fresh new project, and trying to configure the database connections, but it fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jhipster

The command:

```
mvn liquibase:diff -X
```

with mysql setting on jhipster fails on mac-os

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (default-cli) on project jeces: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (default-cli) on project jeces: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:373)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
```

Comment: this stacktrace is useless if you arent saying what you are trying to do, what you are expecting to happen, and what code caused this to happen

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the java runtime version(java 8 is required), and missing configuration in application_dev.xml:
     driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
          defaultSchema: jeces
         referenceUrl: hibernate:spring:my.app.domain? dialect=my.app.utils.MySQL5InnoDBCompressedDialect
        referenceDriver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        verbose: true
        dropFirst: false
        logging: debug

once i ran :
mvn spring-boot:run
mysql is working